# nice email to users

Tags: php, css

when it is to my website send email out to users so send some such bland and grime, so that's how I'd like to like / get some color on the page that is being a little style.

I talk with a friend and he says it is possible to style email that you send to users who register on the site. so it is not just such a boring email use get.

Hope you understand otherwise you are very welcome to ask me

I hope you can help me

Can you give me a link or tell what I should do so that I can get a nice email to my users.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT NULL FROM `brugere` WHERE `email` = ?')) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    if ($count > 0)
    {
        $user_found = 1;
    }
    }
    if(!isset($user_found))
    {
    if($_POST["password"] != $_POST["gentag"])
    {
        $errors = 1;
        echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Skrive ens password p&#229; siden..</li>";
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password']) && empty($_POST['gentag']))
    {
        $errors = 1;
        echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Skrive et password p&#229; siden..</li>";
    }

    if(!isset($errors))
    {
    $pb = null;
    include "class.upload.php";
    $handle = new Upload($_FILES['file']);

    if($handle->uploaded)
    {
    //lidt mere store billeder
    $handle->image_resize = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
    $handle->image_x = 220;
    $handle->Process("profil/store");

    //til profil billede lign..
    $handle->image_resize = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
    $handle->image_y = 75;
    $handle->image_x = 75;
    $handle->Process("profil");
    $pb = $handle->file_dst_name;

        echo "<h2>Tak for du opret dig hos xx.dk</h2>";
    ?>
    <img src="http://xx.dk/ (...) echo $pb;?>" alt="profilbillede" height="75" width="75"><br />
    <?php
    echo "<li id=\"check_ok\">Dit billede blev upload</li>";
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <img src="http://xx.dk/ (...) alt="profilbillede" height="128" width="128"><br />
    <?php
    echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Du upload intet billede. Vi har dog valgt et profil billede for dig.</li>";
    $pb = 'bruger_intet.png';
    }
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `brugere` (`email`, `katogori`, `djnavn`, `profilbillede`, `profiltekst`, `facebook`, `booking`, `password`, `code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {

    $stmt->bind_param('sissssssi', $email, $katogori, $djnavn, $profilbillede, $profiltekst, $facebook, $booking, $password, $code);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $katogori = $_POST["kategori"];
    $djnavn = $_POST["djnavn"];
    $profilbillede = $pb;
    $profiltekst = $_POST["tekst"];
    $facebook = $_POST["facebook"];
    $booking = $_POST["booking"];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $code = rand(111111111,999999999);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $to      = $email; // den som skal modtage mailen!
    $subject = "Hej xx.dk - Godkendt brugere konto"; // sende fra
    $msg    = "Tak for du vil opret dig på xx.dk!. \n \n For at kun activate din konto skal du bare klikke på dette link her: \n \n http://xx.dk/ (...) \n \n Du kan ikke besvar den her email!!";
    $header = "from:xx.dk - Godkendt Profil!! <support@xx.dk>";                

    if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $header))
    {
        echo "<li id=\"check_ok\">Tilsendt e-mail til; $to - Tjek email</li>";
    }
        } 
            else
            {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Der findes allerede en bruger med denne mail - G&#248;r et fors&#248;g mere <a href=\"http://xxx.dk/ (...) igen...</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: It's an email... what you sent is what they'll get. if you want to send something 'spicy', then send something 'spicy'. How to go about that is up to you. We don't write code for you, we just help fix problems with code you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use HTML if you provide the correct headers.

Example:

```
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```